# Ninja forms post process

Tags: wordpress, email, ninja-forms

Good morning everyone,

I am working on an API of Enormail and want data from a ninja form send to the Enormail (similar to Chimpmail). Unluckily Enormail isn't as supported as Chimpmail, but my client would like to use this service.

Right now I have the following code working in my functions.php but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function add_to_enormail( $form_id ) {
   global $ninja_forms_processing;
   $form_id = $ninja_forms_processing->get_form_ID();
   if (  $form_id == 2 || $form_id == 3 ) {
       switch ($form_id) {
       case 1: //Form 1 
           $ninjamail = $ninja_forms_processing->get_field_value( 6 );
           break;
       case 2: //Form 2
           $ninjaname = $ninja_forms_processing->get_field_value( 13 );
           $ninjamail = $ninja_forms_processing->get_field_value( 10 );
           break;
     }  
   }
  require_once ('/emapi/emapi.php');
  $em = new emapi('API KEY OF USER', 'JSON');
  $result = $em->contacts->add('API OF CERTAIN LIST', $ninjaname, $ninjamail);
};

add_action( 'ninja_forms_post_process', 'add_to_enormail' );
```

If I add the require_once code inside a different php file and call it directly a user it being added to the Enormail service, so the API is working fine.
But it seems I can't get the data filled inside the fields and place it inside the API to add user to mailing list.

What is going wrong here.
Thanks

Comment: `require_once ('/emapi/emapi.php');` are you sure about the file path? NB: `/` refers to the root directory.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the correct filepath should be ('emapi/emapi.php')

But still the variables $ninjaname and $ninjamail aren't working properly. If I just add strings like $result = $em->contacts->add('API OF CERTAIN LIST', 'Henk Rensenbrink', 'my email'); it will add correctly, but with variables it does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about the file path? `require_once ('/emapi/emapi.php');`

`/` refers to the root directory. Check your file path.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the correct filepath should be ('emapi/emapi.php') But still the variables $ninjaname and $ninjamail aren't working properly. If I just add strings like $result = $em->contacts->add('API OF CERTAIN LIST', 'Henk Rensenbrink', 'my email'); it will add correctly, but with variables it does nothing. 

I also tried:
$result = $em->contacts->add('API OF CERTAIN LIST', ' . $ninjaname . ', ' . $ninjamail . ');

Comment: Then please check your field_id for email and name.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_to_enormail() {
    global $ninja_forms_processing;
    $form_id = $ninja_forms_processing->get_form_ID();
    if ( $form_id == 3 ) {
            $ninjaname = $ninja_forms_processing->get_field_value( 13 );
            $ninjamail = $ninja_forms_processing->get_field_value( 10 );
    } else if ( $form_id == 2 ) {
            $ninjaname = $ninja_forms_processing->get_field_value( 14 );
            $ninjamail = $ninja_forms_processing->get_field_value( 6 );
    }
require_once ('emapi/emapi.php');
$em = new emapi('API KEY', 'JSON');
$result = $em->contacts->add('LIST API', $ninjaname, $ninjamail);
};

add_action( 'ninja_forms_post_process', 'add_to_enormail' );
```

This solved my issue, both forms from ninja forms are now sending data to Enormail. Also thanks Khorshed Alam for pointing out the beginning / of the directory.